# Исчез перевод об уже предложенной правке в очереди "первые вопросы"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок, первые-вопросы

Проблема в очереди "первые вопросы". Если я уже предложил правку, то в очереди высвечивается об этом сообщение. Вот только перевода нет:

[image: Дефект]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавил перевод:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17005

Будет в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2023.3.27.43347